# JavaScript function won't work no matter what I try

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am brand new to JavaScript and embarrassed to say that I can't figure this out. I am trying to create a website that parses first and last names to output email addresses. I moved the onclick() function outside the onload() and that has only created more issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I apologize for my ignorance.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Email Address Title</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
    <h3>Enter your first and last name and then click the button below to get your Email Account info.</h3>
  </header>

  <main>
    <section class="inputarea">
      <p>First Name: <input type="text" id="fname"></p>
      <p>Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname"></p>
      <button id="genemail">Generate Email</button></section>
    <section class="outputArea"></section>
  </main>
  <br><hr>
  <footer id="by-line">CIS 425 - JavaScript Practice</footer>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  //alert("Just finished loading the webpage in the window.");

  
  
}

document.getElementById("genemail").onclick = processForm(){
 // alert("Just finished loading the webpage in the window.");
  var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;

  console.log(firstname + " " + lastname);

  var label = document.getElementsByClassName("outputArea");

  label[0].innerHTML = "Your Email Address: " + firstname + "." + lastname + "@gmail.com";
  
  document.getElementById("by-line").innerHTML = document.getElementById("by-line").innerHTML + " / Created By: Tony Vance";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `document.getElementById("genemail").onclick = processForm(){` is the problem, you can not name the function `processForm` here. If you change it to the keyword `function` it works just fine, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jsk0byvu/

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want assign function to `onclick` event directly you should use an anonymous function:

```
document.getElementById("genemail").onclick = function(){
 // alert("Just finished loading the webpage in the window.");
  var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;

  console.log(firstname + " " + lastname);

  var label = document.getElementsByClassName("outputArea");

  label[0].innerHTML = "Your Email Address: " + firstname + "." + lastname + "@gmail.com";
  
  document.getElementById("by-line").innerHTML = document.getElementById("by-line").innerHTML + " / Created By: Tony Vance";
}
```

If you don't want use an anonymouse function and your function is parameterless then define your function separately and assign it:

```
function processForm(){
 // alert("Just finished loading the webpage in the window.");
  var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;

  console.log(firstname + " " + lastname);

  var label = document.getElementsByClassName("outputArea");

  label[0].innerHTML = "Your Email Address: " + firstname + "." + lastname + "@gmail.com";
  
  document.getElementById("by-line").innerHTML = document.getElementById("by-line").innerHTML + " / Created By: Tony Vance";
}

document.getElementById("genemail").onclick = processForm;
```

Comment: Appreciate the thorough response, works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("genemail").addEventListener("click", processForm, false);
function processForm(){
 alert("Just finished loading the webpage in the window.");
   var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;

  console.log(firstname + " " + lastname);

  var label = document.getElementsByClassName("outputArea");

  label[0].innerHTML = "Your Email Address: " + firstname + "." + lastname + "@gmail.com";
  
  document.getElementById("by-line").innerHTML = document.getElementById("by-line").innerHTML + " / Created By: Tony Vance";
}
```